# Pardot auto-complete on external forms via cookie matching

Tags: pardot

is it possible to retrieve certain fields values into a form via Pardot API if you can identify the person via their Pardot cookie?

It's possible of course with Pardot forms but I'm not sure if it's possible when using form handlers on external forms

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, though you would want to be very careful of the security considerations.

You don't want to have the browser issue the Pardot API requests. You will want something on your web server to do that on behalf of the prospect.

Basically, web request comes in, it would load some javascript that you prepared in a Pardot File (so that you can access the Pardot cookie) which gets the prospect id from the cookie and basically ask your web endpoint to retrieve the data...and then populate the form.  You might have to handle CORS.

Your web endpoint that is called by the javascript would then need to:

1. Login to Salesforce to get oAuth token (depending on your infrastructure you may choose to cache the token)
2. Using the oAuth token and the Business Unit ID, you could then issue API requests.

In short, it's not nearly as easy as what the Pardot Form provides, but that's a tradeoff chosen when Form Handlers are in play.

Hope this helps!